# Parse string using batch script

Tags: string, parsing, batch-file

How can i parse string using batch script?

Goal is to save in a array everything under **Import:** and strip out "#head"
for example --> "//MPackages/Project/config/abc.txt" and "//Packages/Project/config/cde.txt"

test.txt

```
Version: 4.5.0
Import:
   //MPackages/Project/config/abc.txt                       #head
   //Packages/Project/config/cde.txt                        #head
View:
  //MPackages/Project/config/ac.txt                     #head
  //Packages/Project/config/de.txt                      #head
```

MY try

```
@echo off

set buildlog="devel.p4inc"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in  (devel.p4inc) do  (
if /i "%%A"=="Import:" set "import=true"
IF DEFINED import (echo %%A)

)
```

Comment: Have you tried a `for /f` loop, beginning capture of the first token of each line until the first 2 characters of token 1 is no longer `//`?

Comment: yes, but how would it know to only take from Import: and not from View:?

Comment: You should enable delayed expansion.  `if /i "%%I"=="Import:" set "import=true"` and begin capturing on the next loop iteration. Then `if defined import if not "!variable:~0,2!"=="//" goto next` to break out of the loop.  Show what you've tried so far and you'll get answers.

Comment: @rojo - thank you for quick replies.. please take a look at my original question.. i have added my try script.. but i'm still stuck..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
set "vf=version.txt"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set counter=1
for /f "usebackq tokens=1 delims=#" %%a in ("%vf%") do (
    set "line=%%a"
    if "!line:View=!" neq "!line!" if "!in!" equ "true"  (
        set in=false
        rem echo ###
    )

    if "!in!" equ "true" (
        set "_!counter!_=%%a"
        set /a counter=counter+1
    )
    rem echo !line!
    if "!line:Import=!" neq "!line!" (
        set in=true
        rem echo --
    )

) 

set _
```

try this.It should set the desired variables in numbered list  like `_1_` ; `_2_` ; ...

Answer (score 1):

This is what I had in mind:

```js
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "buildlog=devel.p4inc"
set idx=0

for /F "usebackq" %%A in ("%buildlog%") do (
    if defined import (
        set "config=%%A"
        if "!config:~0,2!"=="//" (
            set "config[!idx!]=%%A"
            set /a idx += 1
        ) else set "import="
    ) else if /i "%%A"=="Import:" set "import=true"
)

rem // display config array
set config[
```